'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided' in DigitalOcean Spaces
My django app saves user-uploaded files to my s3 bucket in DigitalOcean Spaces(using django-storages[s3], which is based on amazon-s3) and the path to the file is saved in my database. However when I click the url in located in the database it leads me to a page with this error:
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
The actual url, for example, looks something like this:
https://my-spaces.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/media/uploads/Recording_2.mp3?AWSAccessKeyId=DO009ABCDEFGH&Signature=Y9tn%2FTZa6sVlGGZSU77tA%3D&Expires=1604202599. Ideally the url saved should be https://my-spaces.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/media/uploads/Recording_2.mp3
This actually also impacts other parts of my project because the url will be accessed later using requests but because of this error I get status [402].
My settings.py is this:
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'DO009ABCDEFGH'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'Nsecret_key'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'bucket_name'
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://transcribe-spaces.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'
}

AWS_MEDIA_LOCATION = 'media/'
PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION = 'media/'
MEDIA_URL = '%s%s' % (AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL, AWS_MEDIA_LOCATION)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'mysite.storage_backends.MediaStorage'

The url that is saved contains the Access Key, the Signature that was used to write the file to the bucket and a timeout. I want all of that to not be there when the url to the file is saved in the database. I've tried to edit the MEDIA_URL, AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME and other settings but they either caused errors that broke the app or did nothing at all.

This should help,
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ''
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = ''
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'space_name'
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = 'nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=31536000'}
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 'transcribe-spaces.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com'

PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION}/'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'mysite.storage_backends.PublicMediaStorage'

Digital ocean spaces

Thanks. However, when I tried to upload a file I got this error: raise ValueError("Invalid endpoint: %s" % endpoint_url) web-1  | ValueError: Invalid endpoint: nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
